# Como utilizar renderAjax Yii2

Tags: php, jquery, yii2

una consulta, vengo tratando de utilizar renderAjax pero no hay forma, alguno podria mostrarme un ejemplo de como utilizarlo correctamente?. Cuando intento utilizarlo no me carga absolutamente ningun estilo, ni el layout ni nada, solo la vista que le indico. Gracias

Parte del controlador

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Sectores();
    if(Yii::$app->request->isAjax){
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) { 
            Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('success',['message' => Html::encode('El registro se guardó correctamente')]);
            return $this->renderAjax('create',['model' => new Sectores]);                           
        }                                       
    } else {           
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model
        ]);
    }
}

public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    $searchModel = new SectoresSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
    if(Yii::$app->request->isAjax){
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {               
            Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('success',[
                'message' => Html::encode('El registro se actualizo correctamente'),
            ]);
        }else{
            Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('error',[
                'message' => Html::encode('El registro no se pudo actualizar'),
            ]); 
        } 
        return $this->renderAjax('index',['searchModel' => $searchModel,'dataProvider' => $dataProvider]); 
    } else {
        return $this->render('update', ['model' => $model]);
    }
}
```

Vista

```html
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\helpers\Url;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use yii\widgets\Pjax;
use yii\web\View;
use kartik\form\ActiveForm;
use demogorgorn\ajax\AjaxSubmitButton;

?>
<!-- Notificaciones -->
<?php foreach (Yii::$app->session->getAllFlashes() as $message):; ?>
        <?php
        \lavrentiev\widgets\toastr\NotificationFlash::widget([
            'type' => (!empty($message['type'])) ? $message['type'] : 'danger',
            'title' => (!empty($message['title'])) ? Html::encode($message['title']) : 'Title Not Set!',
            'message' => (!empty($message['message'])) ? Html::encode($message['message']) : 'Message Not Set!',
        ]);
        ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<!-- Fin notificaciones -->

<div class="form-group mt-3 card-grid p-3">
    <?php Pjax::begin(['id' => 'pjax-container']); ?>   
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(
        [
            'id' => $model->formName(), 
            'enableClientValidation' => true, 
            'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
            'validationUrl' => Url::toRoute(['sectores/validation','scenario' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'create' : 'default']), 
            'fieldConfig' => ['errorOptions' => ['encode' => false, 'class' => 'd-none']],
            'errorSummaryCssClass' => 'alert alert-danger',
        ]
    ); ?>
    <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?> 

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <?= $form->field($model, 'descripcion')->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'autocomplete' => "off", 'autofocus' => true]) ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <?php AjaxSubmitButton::begin([
                'label' => 'Guardar',
                'useWithActiveForm' => $model->formName(),
                'ajaxOptions' => [
                    'type'=>'POST',
                    'url'=>$model->isNewRecord ? 'create' : Url::to(['update', 'id' => $model->id_sector]),
                    'success' => new \yii\web\JsExpression('function(data){                        
                        $(".main-content").html(data)                                              
                    }')
                ],
                'options' => ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'type' => 'submit'],
                ]);
            AjaxSubmitButton::end(); ?> 
            <?= Html::a('Cancelar', ['cancelar'], ['class'=>'btn btn-danger']) ?>            
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>  
    <?php Pjax::end(); ?>
   
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Qué haz intentado? muestranos en código.

Comment: Lo cambie tantas veces que ya ni se cual era la forma. Pero basicamente si yo tengo un formulario y quiero ejecutar el submit y mandar la peticion ajax, que deberia poner en el controlador para que cargue la vista index sin recargar la pagina?, si consigo algun resultado ahora lo edito.

Comment: Qué es lo que quieres cuando dices que quieres mandar la petición ajax sin recargar la página? quieres validar o hacer el submit directo con ajax? sé más específico

Comment: El submit. Ya estoy medio perdido. La pregunta es, se puede hacer el submit desde el formulario y pasar a ver la vista index sin recargar?. Disculpen si no me hago entender u.u

Comment: lo que puedes hacer es mandar la vista por ajax y la respuesta sobreescribir el container, pon tu código para poder ayudar

Comment: Al final esa es la forma que encontre aunque dudo que funcione así realmente. No se si sea la manera correcta pero me ha funcionado. Muchas gracias

Comment: el metodo renderAjax no te añade estillos ni layout ni nada , se usa para devolver una informacion a cliente y desde este añadirlo a algun div

Comment: El problema que he visto ahora es que me duplica algunos assets.